# How can I create a subdictionary in python that overwrites the superdictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, types

I wanted to create a dictionary from another one, in a way if I edited the smaller one it'll automatically edit the larger one

```
>>> d = {'v1':1,'v2':3,'v4':2}
>>> d2 = {k:d[k] for k in ['v1','v4']}
>>> d2['v1'] = 3
>>> print(d.items())
dict_items([('v1', 1), ('v2', 3), ('v4', 2)])
```

expected result:

```
> dict_items([('v1', 3), ('v2', 3), ('v4', 2)])
```

Comment: `d.update(d2)` should update `d` according to `d`.

Comment: you can make a function to update automatically instead of using `d.update` everytime.

Comment: If you want I will post  that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might subclass `dict` (or `collections.abc.Mapping`) to link a subdictionary to superdictionary (called `base` below):

```
class subdict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, base=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.base = base

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        if self.base:
            self.base.__setitem__(key, value)
```

Then, you can use it in the following way to get the result from your example:

```
>>> d = {'v1':1,'v2':3,'v4':2}
>>> d2 = subdict({k:d[k] for k in ['v1','v4']}, base=d)
>>> d2['v1'] = 3
>>> print(d.items())
dict_items([('v1', 3), ('v2', 3), ('v4', 2)])
```

Comment: Well, `d2` is smaller and gets constructed in the same way as in the OP's example.

Comment: comment was for the previous answer you posted `d2=d`. anyways delete the comment.Cheers

Answer (score 0):

One way is by using `update()`.

```
>>> d = {'v1':1,'v2':3,'v4':2}
>>> d2 = {k:d[k] for k in ['v1','v4']}
>>> d2['v1'] = 3
>>> d.update(d2)
>>> print(d.items())
dict_items([('v1', 3), ('v2', 3), ('v4', 2)])
```

But you have to make sure you update `d` everytime you change `d2`.